# what would be the phrase or Idiom for a situation where a person is friendly with both the good and bad folks as per their convenience

Tags: idiom-requests

To describe a situation where a person is friendly with both the good and bad folks as per their convenience.

Comment: You could say he [*runs with the hare and the hounds,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22runs+with+the+hare+and+the+hounds%22) but it's a bit dated/literary.

Comment: Yesss that's it. This is the idiom that I wanted. I was not getting it. Thank you.

Comment: Runs with the hare and hunts with the hound.

Comment: Indeed. Or [*runs with the **fox** and hunts with the hounds.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22runs+with+the+fox+and+hunts+with+the+hounds%22&oq=%22runs+with+the+fox+and+hunts+with+the+hounds%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...20657.20657.0.21957.1.1.0.0.0.0.131.131.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.2JO_morIJqY)